# When do the different types of SSL certificate matter?

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have my site on a wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy.

My client is one of the major banks in Europe.  From inside their network, they cannot access my site https://www.example.com  They get an error.  But, if they go to http://www.example.com, they can access it.

(I set up my site to accept both http and https to test this).

Because they can get to http://www.example.com, I'm thinking it's not a DNS issue or something with their proxy server.

Could it be related to my wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy?

I noticed there are also standard SSL certificates(not wildcards), and SSL OV and SSL EV certificates.  Would these make a difference?

Here's the webserver config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ProxyPass         / http://localhost:8092/
    ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:8092/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    LogLevel info

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ProxyPass         / http://localhost:8092/
    ProxyPassReverse  / http://localhost:8092/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you share the webserver configuration for your site?

Comment: Hi Jorge - Sure, I can.  Can you let me know what you want to see?  I'm not very technical so I'm not sure what 'webserver configuration' means. :)  Thanks!

Comment: By webserver configuration I mean the configuration file where the webserver software (such as apache or nginx) is being configured to handle SSL enabled traffic. Or maybe you're using some sort of control panel?

Comment: Also, you can try putting your website's address here: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and check for any possible errors.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me find the webserver configs.  I tried ssllabs.com and i got a C rating.  The algorithms SHA1with RSA is weak.  Also, in protocoles, I get SSL3 is insecure.  I'm also vulnerable to a POODLE attack.  Could these reasons be why a bank's network is not letting its users to my site?

Comment: It seems unlikely that this is the cause. In case your site is public, could you share the address?

Comment: Jorge - I added config info.  Any look off?

Comment: Can we please stop using 'SSL' as though it meant 'SSL *certificate*'? It doesn't.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything particularly wrong with the configuration, although it can be improved. You could start by disabling older versions of the protocol. Adding this line to the config will disable the versions currently deemed as insecure:  
`SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3`  
  
Also, is there any chance we can get more information about the error your client is getting?